# How to give two different classes the same interface?

Tags: java

Can I give 2 different classes (that I cannot modify as they are autocreated webservice classes) the same interface?

Problem: I have several autocreated webservice classes, that have a method with the same signature. But as the classes have no common interface, I cannot group them and thus cannot call both of them from a single method.

Example:

```
class A {
  void sameMethod();
}
class B {
  void sameMethod();
}


class MyService() {
  //I cannot do the following as I cannot group A and B with the same interface
  void callAorB(<Class A or B> object) {
     object.sameMethod();
  }
}
```

Will it still be somehow possible to just execute òbject.sameMethod()`even though I cannot make a common reference between`class A`and`class B`?

Comment: why can't you have them implement same interface, and in your service method signature put the interface type? instead of concrete classes?

Comment: why not define an interface and make them implement it?

Comment: The inability to declare that some class implements an interface in such-and-such way is indeed one of the greatest weaknesses of Java.

Comment: @Ingo hmm, declaring an interface at runtime would be interesting. But it sounds like more reflection

Comment: @Cruncher I mean at compile time, of course ... making the Compiler generate the code that creates the Adaptor and all the Rest of the Boilerplate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't modify the classes then no, you can't force the interfaces onto the objects. You can however create an interface and two [adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) which implement this interface.

Comment: @ant there is no one "correct" solution - don't block creativity :)

Comment: true, there is no one but this is one of them

Answer (score 2):

The hacked solution would be:

```
if(object instanceof A)
   ((A)object).sameMethod();
else if(object instanceof B)
   ((B)object).sameMethod();
```

but if you can make them implement an interface would be much better

Comment: You don't really want to do this in real world applications

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza why not ?

Comment: @alfasin because it is hard to maintain when you start getting new implementations like `C` or `D` classes... and this can be oversimplified by using an adapter (as you already voted in another answer). Also, note that Cruncher even says this is a *hacked* solution, so it is not a real solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this warrants a downvote. I warned at the beginning of the post that it is in fact a hacked solution. It is a solution though, and adds value to anyone wanting to do this, quick and easy

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the OP specifically stated he refers to two classes. This is a good solution! Adapters might be more elegant and more "object oriented" but this is definitely *easier* to maintain then writing a new adapter for C or D

Comment: instanceof exists in this language for a reason, what else if not to hack something together in a pinch?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza don't get caught in words. Hack is something that's considered good: here in the bay area we call ourselves hackers: http://paulgraham.com/gba.html

Comment: *instanceof exists in this language for a reason, what else if not to hack something together in a pinch?* so you should also promote usage of `goto` as well...

Comment: @alfasin by your link, this hack falls in this sense: *It's called a hack when you do something in an ugly way*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza keep on reading baby! don't take words out of their context ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza fancy or clever might be debatable. **Usefulness** isn't: this solution is definitely useful hence shouldn't be downvoted. Oh well...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza frankly, I would not mind having goto in the language. In minute cases (like instanceof) it can actually be easier than having to nest a block of code deeper. goto is sometimes simply more natural.